# php - mysql update array is very slow

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Mysql base is about 13000 lines, and update time take about 40 minut.
I thinked that

```
foreach ($result->GetProductBarcodeListResult->ProductBarcodeList->ProductBarcodeas $b)
```

is take new connection to remote server every time, and moved all results to own array, but it doesnt helped.

Please help, how the updating can be more faster?

UPDATE - mysqli, but it not give any more speed.

```
public function getProductBarcodes() 
{
    global $db;
    try
    {
        $this->init();
        $request = new GetProductBarcodeListRequest();
        $params = new GetProductBarcodeList();
        $params->GetProductBarcodeListRequest = $request;
        $result = $this->soapClient->GetProductBarcodeList($params);

    if($result->GetProductBarcodeListResult->ProductBarcodeList->ProductBarcode)
    {
        $eanlist= array();

        foreach ($result->GetProductBarcodeListResult->ProductBarcodeList->ProductBarcode as $b)
        {
            $b->SupplierCode = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,"AC".$b->SupplierCode);
            $b->Barcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$b->Barcode);   
            $eanlist[] = array("eancode" => $b->Barcode,"skuean" => $b->SupplierCode);
        }

        foreach ($eanlist as $eanrow) {
            mysqli_query($db, "
                    UPDATE _new_products
                    SET ean = '$eanrow[eancode]'
                    where sku = '$eanrow[skuean]'
                    ; ");  

        }

        echo "EAN UPDATE DONE!\n";
    }
    //echo "<pre>".     print_r($result,1) . '</pre>';
}
catch(SoapFault $e) {
    echo '<xmp>' . $this->soapClient->__getLastRequestHeaders()  .  $this->soapClient->__getLastRequest() .   '</xmp>';
    echo "<pre>".   print_r($e,1) . '</pre>';
}
}
```

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with prepared Ssatements.

Comment: @Jens you know, you can educate people about ext/mysql being deprecated without **YELLING** at them ;)

Comment: Is your table InnoDB or MyIsam?

Comment: What indexes do you have set (if any)? Indexes are good for reading, but bad for writing. If possible, one often removes indexes before updating a large number of rows with indexed fields – that makes the updates/inserts go quicker – and adds them again later on (rebuilding an index “in one go” is usually much faster, than having to re-create/update it on every single change.) Be aware that this might lead to problems if you are relying on indexes to keep column values unique or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following function for updating a single column. Taken from [here](http://edmondscommerce.github.io/mysql/very-high-speed-batch-update-multiple-rows-of-a-table-in-single-query.html)

```
<?php
function bulkUpdateSingleColumn($table, $id_column, $update_column, array &$idstovals){
    $sql = "update $table set $update_column = CASE  ";
    foreach($idstovals as $id=>$val){
        $sql .= " WHEN '$id' THEN '$val' \n";
    }
    $sql .= " END 
    WHERE $id_column in (" . implode(',', array_keys($idstovals)) . ")";
    //debugging info
    echo '<small>'.$sql.'</small>';
    $idstovals=array();
    //  db_query($sql);

}
$eanlist = array("sku1"=>"ean1","sku2"=>"ean2");
$table = '_new_products';
$id_column = 'sku';
$update_column = 'ean';
bulkUpdateSingleColumn($table, $id_column, $update_column,   $eanlist);
?>
```

Comment: i have sku and ean in foreach both

Comment: @MaxS whats is the issue? Did you try this above code ?

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '&', expecting '('

Comment: Nope, <small>update _new_products set ean = CASE   WHEN 'sku1' THEN 'ean1'
 WHEN 'sku2' THEN 'ean2'
 END
    WHERE sku in (sku1,sku2)</small>EAN UPDATE DONE!

Comment: What happened ? Issue Solved ?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed sku from longtext to varchar (255), and addedindex. This is solved  problem